# How to set text in center between parent left and right tag

Tags: html, css

I have this layout of my web page, here last `div` tag `<div>{this.props.status}</div>` is in left end. I want to set it in center between rock and scissors button.

[image]

Expected

[image]

```
<div className="AppTitle">
<b>Score: {this.props.score}</b>
<div>
  <RoundedButton text="Rock" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
  <RoundedButton text="Paper" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
  <RoundedButton text="Scissors" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
</div>

<div>{this.props.status}</div>

</div>
```

App.css

```
.AppTitle {
  margin: 50px;
}

.Button {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

What is the way to do it in HTML ?

Comment: Could you maybe provide a working example?

Comment: @RickyDam Do you mean expected output ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this for css.

```css
.AppTitle {
  margin: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
 }

.button {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.status{text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="AppTitle">
<b>Score: -1</b>
<div>
  <Button class="button">Rock</Button>
  <Button class="button">Paper</Button>
  <Button class="button">Scissors</Button>
  
</div>

<div class="status">Computer Won</div>

</div>
```

**EDITED**

Here added four button & background this one clear.

```css
.AppTitle {
  margin: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#b5b5b5;
 }

.button {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.status{text-align:center;background:#ccc;}
```

```html
<div class="AppTitle">
<b>Score: -1</b>
<div>
  <Button class="button">Rock</Button>
  <Button class="button">Paper</Button>
  <Button class="button">Scissors</Button>
  <Button class="button">Rock</Button>
 
  
</div>

<div class="status">Computer Won</div>
```

**UPDATED**

Make parent div to center.

```css
.wrapper{text-align:center;}
.AppTitle {
  margin:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#b5b5b5;
  text-align:left;
 }

.button {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.status{text-align:center;background:#ccc;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="AppTitle">
<b>Score: -1</b>
<div>
  <Button class="button">Rock</Button>
  <Button class="button">Paper</Button>
  <Button class="button">Scissors</Button>
 
</div>

<div class="status">Computer Won</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does `display:inline-block;` do ?

Comment: Set parent div display to inline-block means width accordingly change depends on child elements maximum width. So all the elements takes equal width. Then set last div text align to center. In case you add four button last div align center in between four butttons.

Comment: Well. What I have to change if I want to move this complete layout in the center of the web browser ?

Comment: `.wrapper{text-align:center;}` will make all child div in center ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146959/discussion-between-mohamed-mohaideen-ah-and-williams).

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at `.status`, you'll find that it is the same width as the previous `<div>`. To center the text, you'll need to give it the CSS:

```
.status {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Also, `<RoundedButton>` is not a HTML tag. Use `<button>` instead.

```css
.AppTitle {
  margin: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.button {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.status {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="AppTitle">
  <b>Score: -1</b>
  <div>
    <button class="button">Rock</button>
    <button class="button">Paper</button>
    <button class="button">Scissors</button>
  </div>
  <div class="status">Computer Won</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could also work @Williams

```css
.mainContainer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 100%;
}

.outputContainer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 20px;
}

#score {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline;
}

.third {
  width: 30%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="top">
    <span id="score"><b> Score: </b></span>
  </div>
  
  <center>
    <div class="third">
      <button type="button"> Rock </button>
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <button type="button"> Paper </button>
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <button type="button"> Scissors </button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="outputContainer">
      <h2> Computer won! </h2>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep them aligned in most cases and not just as a fix on a certain display, try putting them in one  and using `display: block`, like so

```
<div className="AppTitle"> 
<b>Score: {this.props.score}</b> 
<div> 
    <RoundedButton text="Rock" clickitem={this.clickitem} /> 
    <div style="display:block">
        <RoundedButton text="Paper" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
        <span>{this.props.status}</span>
    </div>
    <RoundedButton text="Scissors" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
</div>
```